# Nothing seems to work to successfully remove index.php

Tags: htaccess

No matter what I try, I can't seem to successfully remove index.php. I'm wondering if the host is lacking some setting in the server environment... otherwise the site hosts just fine.

Here's what I've done:

-- Made an .htaccess file containing nothing but the supported method

(http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

-- Cleared the "Name of your site's index page" field in General Configuration

-- In system/expressionengine/config/config.php, I've tried setting the $config['uri_protocol'] to each of the alternate configurations.

I'm running EE 2.6.1. Can't seem to figure out what's going on, at all.

The only thing I *can* think of is that I'm running from an IP address type URL, e.g. http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/~sitename, but I don't see why that would affect anything.

Thanks to ALL who take a stab at the answer - this is driving me a little bonkers.

Comment: "http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/~sitename" - I'm pretty sure that's your issue. I think I've had the same problem and couldn't get it to work on that temporary URL. You could try editing your local host file so that you bypass the temp URL and have a "proper" url?

Comment: Please, try this: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]

Comment: I think that you need to set the RewriteBase to the user directory used in the temporary address: `RewriteBase /~sitename/`

Comment: Who are your hosts? It may help in discovering some specific hosting information which may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Setting it to RewriteBase /~sitename/ was the answer! Thank you! (Don't know why this didn't occur to me.)

Comment: It may be worth Dylan writing that up as the answer and then Rob can accept it so the fix is clear for others. Peg Leg has also answered with something similar.

Answer (score 1):

As Dylan mentioned, set a [RewriteBase](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase), or modify "/index.php" to something like "/~sitename/index.php"

Comment: Ding ding! :)

Fantastic, this works. Thank you PL.

Answer (score 0):

What actually happens when you do this? You said it doesn't work, but do you see 404 pages, white screens, what?

One thing you could try is changing this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: hey Adrian, thanks. It actually generates a hard 404 error, bypassing the EE error setting, when it's "not working." I also forgot to mention that I tried index with and without the leading slash. (Sorry for these careless omissions, I'm usually more detailed than this.) The solution below was the answer.